# Returning enums by value or reference in C++ and possibility of subset of enums

Tags: c++, enums, arguments, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

**Consider following scenario:**

I need to process fruits which most of the time I get in combinations [but not always, lets assume] so I created `enum` as shown below :

```
enum class ProcessInputFruits {None, Apples, Mangoes, PineApples, Grapes, GrapesAndMangoes, ApplesAndPineApples, All};
```

In my function `ProcessFruits` I am passing this `enum` as argument but at the same time I want to return the type of the fruit that has been processed. [It always processes only one type even when given a combination.. lets say]

Since I need to return only single type so I have created another `enum` containing `ProcessedOutFruit`.

```
enum class ProcessedOutFruit {None, Apples, Mangoes, PineApples, Grapes};
```

This is my function :

```
ProcessFruits(ProcessInputFruits& inputFruits, ProcessedOutFruit& outputFruits) {
     if(inputFruits == ProcessInputFruits::GrapesAndMangoes || 
            inputFruits == ProcessInputFruits::All) {
          if(someCondtion) outputFruits = ProcessedOutFruit::Grapes;
          if(anotherCondition) outputFruits = ProcessedOutFruit::Mangoes;
       }
     return ALL_GOOD_HERE;
}
```

**Question : Is there a better way of doing this ?**

1. Can we have a subset of `enums` so that I can represent `1st enum as superset of 2nd enum` ?
2. Can I use input argument to be updated with the result and sent back [Probably a bad design]
3. Need an update in the function signature ? Please suggest a better one.

What I am trying to achieve :

I am maintaining 2 different enum classes containing almost similar values which I wanted to avoid. But when I think of merging these two enum classes, it takes away the readability/clarity of the function signature

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Comment: Enums are small enough that returning by value is fine.  Only return items by reference when their lifetime continues after leaving the function or scope.

Comment: You have 3 questions, and an answer to all of them is "no idea". What exactly are you trying to achieve/avoid?

Comment: I am maintaining 2 different enum classes containing almost similar values which I wanted to avoid. But when I think of merging these two enum classes, it takes away the readability/clarity of the function signature.. hence the 3 question. I hope I was able to make myself clear. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to be able to detect overlapping elements, is that you can define enums like:

```cpp
enum class Fruits {
    None = 0,
    Apple = 1 << 0,
    Grape = 1 << 1,
    Mango = 1 << 2,
    /* Others */
    // You can define their overlap but it's not needed
    All = Apple | Grape | Mango,
};
```

This way each bit represents whether the `enum` has the given fruit. You can test for the fruit by `enumVar & Fruits::Mango` or for multiple fruits by `enumVar & (Fruits::Mango | Fruits::Apple)`. You can check whether it is just a single fruit as well by `enumVar == Fruits::Mango`.

Comment: This makes lot of sense. What would you suggest for function signature.. ProcessFruits(ProcessInputFruits& input, ProcessInputFruits& output); ?

Comment: I would do `Fruits ProcessFruits(Fruits in)`, since I don't see a reason to pass the input as a reference. This way is not possible with C-style error handling (which you might be doing with `ALL_GOOD_HERE`), so then I would do something like `error_t ProcessFruits(Fruits in, Fruits& out)`, but your function signature works as well. How the signature looks is very much up to personal preference at this point, so as long as it makes sense it should be good